# Remote builds with IntelliJ

Tags: build, ssh, intellij-idea

I am having the following problem:

a) I have a UNIX build environment set up on a remote server I can ssh into
b) I have IntelliJ on Windows

What I would like to do is to edit the files through a remote connection
(similar to the functionality that exists for Emacs) and issue shell commands
such as 'make' and running simple 'test-scripts' which exist on the server..

Are the functions to do this integrated into IntelliJ or will I need a plug-in?

Comment: Not really answering your question, but could you run IntelliJ via X Windows on your Unix server?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a SSH plugin for Intellij IDEA. It is available in https://plugins.jetbrains.com/idea/plugin/1203-ssh

Comment: Looks like a good idea this plugin, too bad it has a lot of bugs. I downloaded it and was unable to use it, having the same issues as commented in the plug-in's page.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still looking for a way to edit files remotely while running Intellij locally, version **2016.3 Ultimate Edition** has a *Remote Server Configuration* option. It allows to access files remotely using either [FTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol), [SFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SFTP) or [FTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS).

More details on how to configure the remote servers can be found in [Intellij's Help Pages](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/creating-a-remote-server-configuration.html).

Comment: This syncs files to remote server, however I don't see how to invoke build remotely. Is this possible?